# How to Create a react apex chart to display data of past 12 months?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, apexcharts

I have a application submitting portal, I which user his/her request. the issue I am facing is to separate data on base created at field which separates data from current month to past 12 months.
The Data format is like this.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "63b3fca07d1f15f5d33e12e0",
    "first_name": "ZANAEN",
    "last_name": "Ullah",
    "date_of_birth": "03/12/2002",
    "cnic_number": "55555-5555555-5",
    "expiry_date": "10/01/2027",
    "current_address": "Qqqq",
    "current_city": "Bhawalpur",
    "permanent_address": "1111",
    "permanent_city": "Bhawalpur",
    "mobile_number": "0000-0000000",
    "loan_ammount": "5000",
    "purpose_of_loan": "Micro-Enterprices",
    "current_occupation": "Job",
    "nature_of_business": "Existing",
    "duration_of_business": "5 years",
    "business_address": "11111",
    "business_city": "Bhawalpur",
    "createdAt": "2022-01-03T10:00:00.562Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-01-03T10:00:00.562Z",
    "applicationId": 22121022,
    "__v": 0
  },
]
```

and the function is like

```
getChartLast1Year(objects) {
    const monthCounts = [];
    const currentMonth = moment().month();
    const currentYear = moment().year();

    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      const month = (currentMonth + i) % 12;
      const year = month < currentMonth ? currentYear - 1 : currentYear;
      const monthData = objects.filter((application) => {
        const createdAt = moment(application.createdAt);
        return createdAt.month() === month && createdAt.year() === year;
      });
      monthCounts.push({
        month: moment().month(month).format("MMM"),
        year: moment().year(year).format("YYYY"),
        count: monthData.length,
      });
    }

    console.log("monthCounts", monthCounts);

    return monthCounts;
  },
```

If anyone can help I would be so thankful